# Need hint in evaluating $\lim_{x\to 0}(\log\frac{1}{x})^x$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

What is the limit of $$\lim_{x\to 0}\Big(\log\frac{1}{x}\Big)^x$$

How can I proceed? I tried putting $x=e^{\log(x)}$ but it did not help.

I would like to have some hints. Please don't provide the complete solution.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The double sided limit does not exist. You probably mean $x\to 0^+$.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If $x=\sqrt2$, what does $\log\left(\frac1x\right)^x$ *mean*?

Comment: @Stammering Do you mean $\ln\left[\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\right]$ or $\left[\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]^x$?

Comment: I think the notation is ambiguous. Do you mean $(\log (1/x))^x$ or $\log ((1/x)^x)$ ? As $x \to 0^+$, both expressions are valid, since $\log (1/x) > 0$ nearby $0^+$, and it can be a base of a function that looks like exponential.

Comment: I have edited the post, @Jam

Comment: @xbh Please see the edited post.

Comment: Can downvoters please explain the reason for downvotes. I know I have not shown any efforts because I have no idea how to proceed and this was the reason I asked for hint not the complete solution. Anyways thanks for the feedback

Comment: @StammeringMathematician Then try to take the logarithm first, and compute that limit. Maybe L'Hopital could do it?

Comment: @Stammering I'm not a downvoter but it could be because you hadn't showed how you'd tried to answer the question (other than mentioning $e^x$) or what resources you'd looked through. There are plenty of prior questions on the site about limits of the form $\lim f(x)^{g(x)}$, whose methods you could have tried to adapt

Comment: @Jam Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to the new edit:
$$\big(\log{\frac{1}{x}}\big)^x=\exp\big(x\log(-\log x)\big)$$
Now $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}{x\log(-\log x)}=\lim_{t\to \infty}{\frac{\log(\log t)}{t}}= \lim_{t\to \infty}{\frac{\log(\log t)}{\log{t}}}\times{\frac{\log{t}}{t}}=0$$

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the OP's question as it was $(\ln(1/x))^x$, not $\ln((1/x)^x)$. See the edit above.

Comment: @Michael The OP didn't change the question, they'd expressed it poorly so there was no way to know what they meant to begin with. The answerers should have checked how to parse the OP's expression before jumping the gun at giving answers. Regardless of whether the answers had good intentions, they're essentially incorrect and leading the OP astray as they answer the wrong question.

Comment: Thank you for responding to the OP's edit.

Comment: Shouldn't you use another variable as to not cause confusion?

Comment: and isn't that limit only available when it is $\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{x}$?

Comment: That is also valid. But if you want (check edit)

Comment: thank you, haven't thought of that

Answer (score 1):

Take 
$$L = \log(\frac{1}{x})^x$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\log(L) =\lim_{x\to0} x\log(\log(\frac{1}{x}))$$

Substitute $$x= 1/t$$ and apply L'Hospital rule.

Answer (score 0):

Well it only makes sense to consider the limit as $x\to 0+$. Write the limit as
$$
\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{\log(1/x)}{1/x}=\lim_{u\to \infty}\frac{\log u}{u}
$$
which you can compute.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the OP's question as it was $(\ln(1/x))^x$, not $\ln((1/x)^x)$. See the edit above.

Comment: Well maybe OP should have been more clear with the brackets the first time around eh?????????